# How can my WPF application (w/ MVVM, Prism) interact with a monolithic MFC application?

Tags: wpf, mfc, interop

I'm developing a WPF front end (using MVVM and Prism) for an existing MFC application. This application is not going to be significantly changed as it is monolithic and lacks any documentation of any kind. Are there any technologies that can either bring these two platforms into the same memory space (best option) or allow them to communicate in synchronously (as the MFC application is by no means thread safe)? To maintain stability, I need the WPF to be an executable.  I've tried attaching it as a dll to the MFC application, but this results in extreme instability.

Comment: Beaware of AirSpace issues. If you want to mix WPF and MFC views then read up on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970688.aspx. We had issues with WPF and Winforms so it could be extra hard for MFC. All the best getting it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option you have is to directly host your MFC in WPF, or embed the WPF in your MFC app as outlined on the [WPF and Win32 Interoperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742522.aspx) MSDN article.  Specifically, check out the two walkthroughs mentioned at the top of that article.

I found embedding WPF in your MFC code much simpler than rehosting your MFC application in WPF.

Hosting WPF in MFC is simply a matter of correctly using the [HwndSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.hwndsource.aspx) class (if you're unafraid of using Managed C++ you can create a nice interop layer and avoid the /clr flag in your MFC project altogether.)

Hosting your MFC application within a WPF application is trickier if you are trying to rehost an MDI application, but it allows you to host the individual frames anywhere you like in your WPF code (using Prism regions, for example.)  In this case, I ended up stripping away all MDI frame management code manually.

To do this I created my own `CMultiDocTemplate`-derived class and override the `OpenDocumentFile()` virtual method to provide my own Frame-opening behaviour.  This method manually created a special `CMDIChildWnd`-derived frame that I had created that overrode any method that interacted with the MDI parent frame window, and passed them to the underlying `CFrameWnd` (bypassing the `CMDIChildWnd`).

First, a helper function object that creates your frame (m_pFrameClass is your special CMDIChildWnd-derived class described above)

*HWND CreateHostedFrame(HWND parent)*

```
CFrameWnd* pFrame = (CFrameWnd*)m_pFrameClass->CreateObject();

CWnd parentWnd;
parentWnd.Attach(parent);
pFrame->LoadFrame(resourceID, WS_CHILD, &parentWnd, pContext);
parentWnd.Detach();

return pFrame->m_hWnd;
```

Then your overridden DocTemplate method (or wherever you create your frames)

*CHostedMultiDocTemplate::OpenDocumentFile:*

```
CDocument* pDocument = CreateNewDocument();

// the following is just for demo purposes.  Use your own mechanism
m_MyWpfShellOrSomething->PleaseCreateAHostedWindowUsing(&CreateHostedFrame);

InitialUpdateFrame(pFrame, pDocument, bMakeVisible);

return pDocument;
```

Your `CMDIChildWnd`-derived class will probably want to override anything that refers to the MDI parent frame (search the MFC `CMDIChildWnd` source for `MDIParent()` or something.)

Of course the final step is updating your CMyApp::OnInitInstance() method to use your specialised MultiDoc template and child frame instead of the other ones.

Comment: I've moved away from this problem by using an IPC channel and hosting the MFC application in my WPF as an external process.  I'm using the copy data method. (similar to this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/InterprocessCommunicator.aspx), but thanks.